# Is there a way to show the Metadata navigation tree , as a left side navigation

Tags: 2013, navigation, managed-metadata, managed-navigation

I have created an enterprise wiki library site collection , then I link it with a managed metadata service . But I need to add the metadata navigation term tree to be displayed on the left navigation links. So that when a user click on a term to filter the Wikis pages and only show the wikis that are linked to this term. Can any one advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the below link to create managed metadata terms for navigation and link it with your wiki pages.https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-2013-Navigation-using-Managed-Metadata-Term-Store.aspx

Once done go to Site Settings, under  Look and Feel click on Navigation.

Select "Managed Navigation" for "Current Navigation" section.Then select the term set you created for navigation

Comment: link goes to a blank page :/